# Android Studio, Flutter sdkmanager not found

Tags: flutter, sdk, android-sdk-manager, android-licenses

So guys, there's a problem with my flutter/android studio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TxV1.png)

I don't know what is the problem, I saw a lot of solution but none of them worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXzRf.png)

I almost select everything, maybe it will fix that but no...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pykBb.png)

you can see my Android SDK Location is C:\Users\molna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk but the flutter doctor -v doesn't recognize I think.

Also if I write in the Visual Studio Code this: flutter run it will say [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjw6H.png)

And if I type in the cmd this: sdkmanager --licenses it says [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZeCd.png)

I will would be very happy, if someone could help me!

I've tried everything I've seen on the internet, but I haven't found anything that helped.

Comment: I think you make some mistakes with System var when setting ENV. Can you try it again with the new one? 
For VS Code: Check your file main.dart. Remove import dart.html. no need to check sdkmanager if it's a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `ANDROID_HOME` variable is pointing to a different location than the actual location of sdk. The second image that you provided has the actual location of the android studio sdk. Copy that path:

```
C:\Users\molna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

and edit the system environment variable called `ANDROID_HOME` and set it to the path above.

For editing system environment variables see:
[IBM set Android_Home variable](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rtw/10.5.1?topic=prwut-setting-changing-android-home-path-in-windows-operating-systems#:%7E:text=Perform%20the%20following%20steps%20to%20change%20the%20value%20of%20the,home%3E%2FAndroid%2FSdk%20.)

Comment: Its changed now, it says Android toolchain - develop for Android devices ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\molna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you attach the error you are getting now?